# "Undefined control sequence" while using conditional equations in LATEX

Tags: cases

I used the below LaTeX commands for writing a conditional equation. Although the output shown is correct, it gives a compilation error "Undefined control sequence". Can anyone please let me know how to correct this?

```
The saturation or clipping function is defined as follows
\[
\textit{clip}\textsubscript{K,w}(w) =
\begin{cases}
    w,& $\Abs${w} \leq 2\textsuperscript{K - 1} - 1 \\
    2\textsuperscript{K - 1} - 1,&   w >  2\textsuperscript{K - 1} - 1\\
    -2\textsuperscript{K - 1} + 1, & w < -2\textsuperscript{K - 1} + 1
\end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: The main problem is that `\Abs` has no default definition. But you also have illegal `$` characters in the formula and you seem to not know about `2^{K-1}` instead of `\textsuperscript`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `\Abs` command defined (unless you define it yourself).

Other points:

1. `\textit` should be `\mathit`
2. No `$` are allowed, you are already in math mode, initiated by `\[`
3. `\textsubscript` and `\textsuperscript` are for *textual* sub/superscripts in *text mode*; for math mode use `_` and `^`.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The saturation or clipping function is defined as follows
\[
\mathit{clip}_{K,w}(w) =
\begin{cases}
  w,              & \lvert w\rvert \leq 2^{K - 1} - 1 \\
  2^{K - 1} - 1,  & w > 2^{K - 1} - 1\\
  -2^{K - 1} + 1, & w < -2^{K - 1} + 1
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A refined version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The saturation or clipping function is defined as follows
\[
\mathit{clip}_{K,w}(w) =
\begin{cases}
  w,              & \lvert w\rvert \leq 2^{K - 1} - 1 \\
  2^{K - 1} - 1,  & w > 2^{K - 1} - 1\\
  -2^{K - 1} + 1, & w < -2^{K - 1} + 1
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, prof. What is the difference of output, in mathmode, between `\mathit` and `\textit`? However +1.

Comment: @egreg Thank you so much for the feedback !

Comment: @Sebastiano `\textit` will use the italic form of the current _text_ font. If you have e.g. text in sans serif, `\textit` will give you italic (well, actually slanted) sans serif, while `\mathit` will use the math fonts.

Comment: @campa Thanks a lot for your comment and help.